# salt-master not working yet error while setting up kubernetes cluster on aws ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, kubernetes

I am trying to setup kubernetes cluster on aws ec2 referring http://www.tothenew.com/blog/setup-kubernetes-cluster-on-aws-ec2/

I ran :

```
[ec2-user@ip-192-168-1-207 kubernetes]$ export KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=aws

[ec2-user@ip-192-168-1-207 kubernetes]$  bash cluster/kube-up.sh
```

Getting error :

```
Attempt 1 to check for SSH to master [ssh to master working]
Attempt 1 to check for salt-master [salt-master not working yet]
Attempt 2 to check for salt-master [salt-master not working yet]
Attempt 3 to check for salt-master [salt-master not working yet]
Attempt 4 to check for salt-master [salt-master not working yet]
Attempt 5 to check for salt-master [salt-master not working yet]
Attempt 6 to check for salt-master [salt-master not working yet]
Attempt 7 to check for salt-master [salt-master not working yet]
Attempt 8 to check for salt-master [salt-master not working yet]
Attempt 9 to check for salt-master [salt-master not working yet]
Attempt 10 to check for salt-master [salt-master not working yet]
Attempt 11 to check for salt-master [salt-master not working yet]
Attempt 12 to check for salt-master [salt-master not working yet]
```

Please let me know what is wrong!